# javascript Looking to find a way to get specific keys from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, path

Hello I was wondering if anybody know of a way to specific keys from objects.
This part of the project is for javascript path . Where it will sort the object keys

here is some examples of what I am talking about

```
var CapitalLetters = {
    "A" : [
      "M40,60 v-20 l10,-20 l10,20 v20 v-15 h-20 ",
     ],
```

```
if (answers2 === CapitalLetters['A'] || CapitalLetters['S'] || LowerLetters['d'] || NumberLetters[4]) {
```

So in the first example is the standard object.
I am trying to get "A" not the value inside .So I can detect if "A" is in my HTML

which is currently

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="v" >
```

NOT "M40,60 v-20 l10,-20 l10,20 v20 v-15 h-20 ",

I feel that I could do this with making more objects But I will have to write over 100 lines of code and will make everything in the end more complicated .
So I was wondering if there is a easier option then making more objects with the keys that I need inside . For each action.

Again I need to get the KEY not the value

Comment: `Object.keys(CapitalLetters).filter(...)`?

Comment: `if (answers2 in CapitalLetters)` will check if the value of answers2 is a key of CapitalLetters

Comment: James I am trying not to do that , For example  I want to sort 'A' and 'B' which are both in CapitalLetters , But for the thing I am doing are needed to be seperate

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `for in`.

```js
var CapitalLetters = {
  A: ["M40,60 v-20 l10,-20 l10,20 v20 v-15 h-20 "],
  B: ["M40,60 v-20 l10,-20 l10,20 v20 v-15 h-20 "],
  C: ["M40,60 v-20 l10,-20 l10,20 v20 v-15 h-20 "],
};

for (const key in CapitalLetters) {
  if (answers2 === CapitalLetters[key][0]) {
    //do something
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I did the else if statement . Is because there are seven possibilites for what I am doing . and I want it to detect if the if statement does not work . I want it to go down to the next else if statement. Then again if that does not work.

but the CapitalLetters[key][0] I never have seen that before I will try that thank you

Comment: @Bryan, the for-in loop actually is doing the same logic as your codes. once it matches the answer2 === Cap[key][0], it will do the job and break the loop.